# Why am I getting site Administrator instead of site owner while doing site.Owner in SharePoint Online CSOM?

Tags: c#, .net, office365, sharepoint-online, csom

I have this code,

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(Url))
            {
                //Validating the User credentials
                ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securepass);
                var site = ctx.Site;
                ctx.Load(site, siteProperties);
                var rootSite = site.RootWeb;
                ctx.Load(rootSite, Properties);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                Console.WriteLine($"Site Owner: {site.Owner.Email}");
```

this is supposed to print me "anil@kaialsh.cf" but instead it prints "Company Administrator", why? Then is there some other way to get Site Owner? please help. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://Tenant.sharepoint.com/"))
        {

            ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(account, secret);
            ctx.Load(ctx.Web,a=>a.AssociatedOwnerGroup.Users);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            if (ctx.Web.AssociatedOwnerGroup!=null)
            {
                foreach (var user in ctx.Web.AssociatedOwnerGroup.Users)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(user.Email);
                }
            }
       }
```

[Using CSOM to Get List of Site Owners](https://office365developer.com/2019/04/10/use-csom-to-get-site-owners/)